# how do i find the betweenness centrality of a node in gremlin?

Tags: graph, gremlin, tinkerpop

The betweenness centrality of a node V is defined as the
proportion of shortest paths between all pairs of nodes that
go through V.

I have looked at the tinkerpop recipes documentation and i don't find it helpful/doesn't work. i.e it returns a

```
......1>
```

when i run the query.

the query ran is:

```
g.V().as("v").repeat(both().simplePath().as("v")).emit().
           filter(project("x","y","z").by(select(first, "v")).
                                       by(select(last, "v")).
                              by(select(all,"v").count(local)).as("triple").
                  coalesce(select("x","y").as("a").
                             select("triples").unfold().as("t").
                             select("x","y").where(eq("a")).
                             select("t").
                           store("triples")). 
                  select("z").as("length").
                  select("triple").select("z").where(eq("length"))).
           select(all, "v").unfold().
           groupCount().next()
```

i am using the airroutes data provided by lawrence as in this guide http://kelvinlawrence.net/book/Gremlin-Graph-Guide.pdf. it does not contain centrality measures.. I have started with the below which would a) not give any cyclic paths and b) emit() modulator to “output” all the traversed vertices

```
g.V().repeat(both().simplePath()).emit()
```

how do i go from here to calculate the betweeness centrailty of the node/ or is there someplace else you would start.

Comment: can you please be more specific about what didn't work with the recipe? getting that type of output from the console is indicative of some form of syntax error where the console is expecting a closing parenthesis or some additional input. please provide the code that you tried.

Comment: please see edit. it was taken from the tinkerpop recipes documentation http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#degree-centrality

Answer (score 1):

You actually modified the query from the Gremlin Recipes site, there should be a comma between `select("t")` and `store("triples")`, not a period. However, this query will probably not work on the air-routes graph as it has way too many paths. As noted below the recipe, the query is only suitable for very small (sub)graphs. Even if you have enough memory for the computation, I think you'll have to wait a good amount of time (hours?) until you see a result.

IMO, you should consider a different centrality algorithm for a graph of this size. In the end, the results don't differ too much between algorithms and usually, the bigger your graph is, the less you care about accurate centrality values for each and every vertex. The classic PageRank algorithm, for example, runs perfectly fine on larger graphs.

Comment: my problem is i can't find any alternative algorithms

Comment: Well, what about `PageRank`? The `PageRank` algorithm processes the full air-route graph in 770 ms on my system.

Comment: i thought page rank was different to betweenness centrality

Comment: It is different, but if you compare the outcomes of several algorithms, you'll see that there are similarities in how they weight the vertices.

Comment: This might be an interesting read for you: https://www.datastax.com/2017/04/reducing-computational-complexity-with-correlate-traversals